# Prove that Feature Flags turned off Items in Production Environment

Tags: design-patterns, .net, git, deployment, software

We want to implement Feature Deploy Flags, so Development Application Environment will have a new Product feature Toggled on. And Release and Production Environment Webpage, it is turned off.

Its toggled through appsettings.json file.

https://launchdarkly.com/blog/what-are-feature-flags/

Our clients, do not like Feature Flag, and want us to Different Source Control Git Branches. The argument is, "We Cannot Ensure, the Features are turned off or toggled off in the Production environment. How do you know there is not new code leakage?"

Well we took screenshots of our APIs not working in Swagger/Postman, additionally showed "Page is not Found in Webpage", when browsing to new feature webpage.

What else can we do to ensure, Deploy Flag Feature are turned off? How would someone prove this?

It will be more confusing for developers to create New Source Control Branches for every toggle, etc.

Application is Net Core C# APIs, with Angular Webpage in Azure Cloud & Devops. Want to apply these feature,

Feature Flags and Router Guards,

**Resources:**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-feature-flags-dotnet-core

https://netbasal.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-implementing-feature-flags-in-angular-applications-d4ae1fd33684

Comment: What kind of software do you make and how is it distributed? Is it SaaS? Is it multi-tenant?

Comment: Report feature flag settings in a health check?  You or your clients probably already have ping/health check services - you could look for presence (or absence) of strings that indicated specific feature flags in the health response; mark service as bad if the wrong features showed up.

Comment: I just left more background info, C# and Angular with Azure Cloud, Property application system for a County in Wisconsin actually cc @ThomasOwens

Comment: hi @davidbak can you explain more with code or source link? sounds interesting

Comment: What are the acceptance criteria which are being used to test and verify that the feature has been implemented correctly?  Those same tests would also surely demonstrate that the feature is not present/enabled (all the tests would yield negative results).

Comment: There are 3rd party services (or you can roll your own) which log and/or alarm when your webservice is bad - isn't responding, or isn't responsive.  You usually provide such a service a "health url" like "https://myservice.mycompany.com/health" - it fetches that url (no caching) once per minute (or more frequently) - and the text in that response tells the "health" of the service.  (Or of course if there's no response ...)  Text can be whatever you like but is typically launch command line, env vars, current cpu/memory/storage state, statistics, etc.  So include your feature flags ...

Comment: ([This link](https://microservices.io/patterns/observability/health-check-api.html) is just one of many hits for "webservice health check" if you want more information ... and also as I said there are commercial 3rd party services for this, you can find them and read up on what you can do with them.)

Comment: The updates and your comment don't answer my question. Who is responsible for this application? Do you provide it as software-as-a-service where you manage the infrastructure and application? Or do you provide the software to be managed by people at your client site as an on-prem solution?

Comment: @ThomasOwens we build the software, and will manage it for them for next 20 years, on Azure Devops Cloud Application and Azure SQL , we manage the maintenance of application also

Comment: why was this question voted down? trying to learn

Comment: (Be sure you want to pull on this thread, but) why does your client trust you to deliver any other part of this system? Then why not this? Note that feature flags *don't* generally prevent code leakage, unless they're applied at build time (which is an anti-pattern of its own).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to slice this.

From a client's standpoint, feature flags can raise some concerns. Is the system well-tested in various combinations of feature flags? Are all of the endpoints (both UI elements and request endpoints) protected against usage when the feature flag is set to a disabled state? When you introduce a third-party to manage those feature flags, there are additional concerns. What happens when the third-party system experiences an outage? Is the ability to toggle the feature flags secure and access well-controlled?

From a developer's standpoint, feature flags add complexity to a system and must be considered throughout the product development life cycle. What features need to be behind a feature flag? What happens if multiple feature flags are interwoven? How do we adequately test in all of the valid states of the system?

Depending on the environment, different types of feature flags are more useful than others. For example, instead of using a third-party service like Launch Darkly, consider a configuration file that requires you to redeploy your system or feature toggles in an administrative UI console. In other cases, feature flags aren't the right solution. Sometimes, [keystone interfaces](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/KeystoneInterface.html) are useful. In other cases, separate branches are the right way to go. The choice depends on the specific requirements of your system.

When you provide software-as-a-service, I do not believe that customers should dictate how you go about building and deploying the software system. There are functional requirements and quality attributes that dictate how you design, build, test, and deploy new features or functionality. There may be regulatory standards at play that need to be treated as requirements on your product as well as the processes used to build it.

As a SaaS vendor, your obligation should be to demonstrate that you meet all of the requirements - regulatory requirements, functional requirements, and desired quality attributes. You should be able to simulate and test under various error and failure conditions to give your client sufficient confidence in your ability to provide the services agreed upon.

Coming from regulated environments, I'm used to questions such as this from clients. My approach is typically:

- Collect information from vendors and suppliers. This may include various industry-standard audits and assessments (ISO 27001 and SOC 2 are common, but others are more industry-specific). Other information may be documented on their website or in a contract - clients and testimonials, case studies, terms of service, and privacy policy.
- Perform a vendor assessment. Using the vendor's information, support how they will support meeting the requirements levied upon the system under design. If the client's documentation is insufficient, using a demo or trial period in a test environment to capture information may be a good idea.
- Allow for your development process to be audited. If you're a larger enterprise, there are various standards you can be audited against. Clients may also want to audit you directly. Have clear descriptions of how you work and how those ways of working satisfy every aspect of the software development life cycle and their requirements.
- Explicitly walk through your testing process. Demonstrate that you have appropriate coverage (preferably automated) around your feature flags. Although I know that it's not necessarily the most useful, things like code coverage reports can demonstrate that you're able to test. Also, explicitly go into how you manage environment access and who can toggle flags. Demonstrations go a long way.
- Have a demonstration environment that mimics production, especially if testing can't be done in production. This can give your clients the ability to understand your application in various states. They can gain confidence in the architecture and even toggle features on and off in different combinations without affecting the state of production.

Answer (score -2):

tbh I agree with you clients, feature flags are bad.

However, this particular complaint can be dealt with in the same way as any "wHaT If ITs WrOnG??!?" question. Test it

You should have end to end or integration tests that confirm the behavior of the deployed application. These test should fail if the incorrect features are turned on or off

Build the tests into the deployment script and allow them to be run against the live environment at any time. If a question arises about whether the live app is working correctly, simply run the tests

Comment: hi Ewan, why are feature flags bad? interesting they are used by google (for A/B user testing), Amazon,  and in Microsoft Net Core system framework

Comment: because they exponentially multiply the paths you need to test.

Comment: hi @Ewan, true, thats a good point, feature flags should be minimal and technical debt according to develop principles I read, isnt it also hard to manage Multiple git branches with merges and cherry picking, and environments,  just to toggle off one feature?

Comment: Feature flags are very useful in many case.  One example:  any code change in a legacy production environment, _especially one with many interacting services_, _especially one with many interactive services some of which you **don't** control yourself_, where even when following best practices you can be bitten by unexpected ramifications of your change - especially _between_ services - and you need to revert ASAP without impacting your production load.  There are plenty of situations where complete testing simply cannot be done.

Comment: dont do that either. add features, have releases with them in

Comment: if you need to revert, revert to previous version dont revert to an untested combination of flags

Comment: Your suggestions - e.g., test completely, run tests at any time against live production, revert if necessary - are fine but aren't useful for 100% of all cases.  There are real world situations - situations where lots and lots of $$$$$ are involved - where these suggestions don't work.  All I'm saying is that there are some use cases where feature tests work fine and work well (compared to the alternatives) - and specifically legacy systems with multiple services interacting and where you can't tolerate much if any downtime and you need to pull the plug _quickly_ is one such situation.

Comment: they work just fine. You have to start considering config changes as being of equal risk as code changes. reverting versions is just as easy, and safer than turning a feature off. routing a proportion of traffic to a different version is better than having a feature flag

Comment: hi @Ewan "dont do that either. add features, have releases with them in " we want releases Excluded in certain releases, etc, ah well, they maybe another question, thanks

Comment: i guess the essence of my point (in this side argument) is that releasing a version without the code in at all is the same as releasing a feature flag off version, except you don't have to test the "what if its on?" path. If you have say a "dark mode" option, then you would test that everything works in both dark and light mode. its the same with feature flags